# How to show thumbnail while playing audio in VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a videoView which is playing both audio and video streams ,but when I am playing audio I dont want screen to be blank instead I want to show an image or thumbnail ,how can I achieve this task ?

Comment: Create a relative layout and then put Video view and a thumbnail into it.

Comment: I need to show the thumbnail inside VideoView